# Not able to Publish Global parameter to ADF using ARM Templates

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to publish Global parameters to ADF using CI pipeline which is generating  dynamic ARM Templates. ARM Template generated is not proper and not having any parameters related to ADF.

Answer (score 1):

Usually if you are using "**live mode**" the Global Parameters are placed in "`Factory`" folder once ARM template is exported.

However, to include global parameters in the ARM template, select "**Include in ARM temple**" check box from the Manage hub.

[image]

Since above is only available in "**Git mode**" and disabled in "live mode" or "Data Factory" mode, if you are using automatic publishing, use PowerShell script method instead. Checkout the [official MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/author-global-parameters#deploying-using-powershell) for detailed steps to Deploying using PowerShell.